# R lattice multiple plot page how to put text in page margin

Tags: r, plot, margin, lattice

I would like to put a title on a page of plots created using R lattice. For example I can put four plots on a page as follows:

```
#load lattice
require(lattice). 
# data
a<-c(1,3,4)
b<-c(1,2,3)
# make plots
plt1<-xyplot(a~b,main="plt1")
plt2<-xyplot(a~b,main="plt2")
plt3<-xyplot(a~b,main="plt3")
plt4<-xyplot(a~b,main="plt4")
# plot plots
plot(plt1, split=c(1,1,2,2),newpage=FALSE)
plot(plt2, split=c(1,2,2,2),newpage=FALSE)
plot(plt3, split=c(2,1,2,2),newpage=FALSE)
plot(plt4, split=c(2,2,2,2),newpage=FALSE)
```

Now how do a put the title "My Page of Plots" centered in the top margin above plt1 and plt3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grid` to push a viewport and add the title:

```
library(grid)
vp2 <- viewport(x = 0.5, y = 1, width = 1, height = .1, just = c("center", "top"))
pushViewport(vp2)
grid.rect(gp = gpar(vol = "blue")) # just to see dimensions/position of the viewport
grid.text("My Title", gp = gpar(cex = 2))
```

You have to play with the position and dimensions of the viewport a bit. And ideally you would also add a top margin to your `lattice` call, such that you create some white space for your title.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it's heading in the right direction ... but how do I set the top margin on the page rather than on each plot to make space for the title? My understanding is the lattice call is acting on each plot not the page?

Comment: @Markm0705 `split` gives you a fixed layout - `position` gives you more control.  See `?print.trellis`. So using `position=c(0,.4,.5,.8)` then `c(.5,.4,1,.8)`, `c(0,0,.5,.4)` and `c(.5,0,1,.4)` will leave 20% free on top for the title.

Comment: Dave thanks that sounds like the solution I'm looking for