# R lattice plot - add outer margin, add text to the margin and move main titles down

Tags: r, lattice

Some years ago I posted a question as to how to add a title to an R lattice plot with the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627075/r-lattice-multiple-plot-page-how-to-put-text-in-page-margin).  However, I'm wondering if there is now a way to use lattice to add an outer margin then add text to the margin.  Some example code is below where I would like to have the title "Iris Histograms" at the top of the output plotting page.  I'm also wondering if there is a way to move the main title on each plot down closer to the histogram?

```
tmp <- "Iris_Hsit.jpg"

jpeg(filename = tmp, width = 20,  height = 20 , units = "cm", 
     pointsize = 5,bg = "white",  res = 600, quality = 75)

pdd <-2
lattice.options(
  layout.heights = list(bottom.padding =list(x = pdd), top.padding = list(x = pdd)),
  layout.widths = list(left.padding = list(x = pdd), right.padding = list(x = pdd))
)

for(i in 1:4){  
  tmp <- histogram(~iris[ ,i], data = iris, aspect = 1, 
                   main = list(names(iris)[i], cex = 2),
                   xlab = list(names(iris)[i]))
  if(i <= 2){
   plot(tmp, split = c(1, i, 2, 2), more = TRUE)
  }else{
    j <- i - 2  
    plot(tmp, split = c(2, j, 2, 2), more = TRUE)
  }
}

dev.off()
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want; is it just to add a title again? There are a bunch of tools now for combining plots produced by the `grid` package. I still use `gridExtra`. Is this what you are wanting? Store plots in list: `lst <- lapply(1:4, function(i)  {
   histogram(~iris[ ,i], data = iris, aspect = 1,  main = list(names(iris)[i], cex = 2),                    xlab = list(names(iris)[i])) })`. Then combine and plot: `gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=lst, as.table=FALSE, top=grid::textGrob("Iris Histograms", gp=gpar(cex=2)))`

Comment: ... just noticed you final sentence. you can move things by using `par.settings`; This shows a couple of things that can be changed `par.settings=list( par.main.text = list(x=grid::unit(0.5, "npc"), y=grid::unit(0, "cm"),  col="red", fontsize=20))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I was hoping that lattice had evolved to t being able to set the outer margin of the plot like 'oma' parameter in base graphics. Also hoping there was something along the lines of mtext which has an outer margin open. Looks like I will have to upgrade my skills to understanding gridExtra.

Comment: okay thanks Mark. I don't think that lattice functionality will change much given its status as a recommended package. While lattice does have some functions to alter margins (as you found with padding) you can always alter these things after the fact with lower level grid functions (which you can't do in base r plots) or combine / add grobs for additional space or text. That's what I use gridExtra for as it takes some of the pain out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Using c.trellis from latticeExtra we can do this:

```
library(latticeExtra)

do.call(c, lapply(iris[1:4], histogram, main = "Iris", xlab = ""))
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

or xyplot.list which also uses latticeExtra and gives the same output:

```
xyplot.list(iris[1:4], FUN = histogram, main = "Iris", xlab = "", y.same = FALSE)
```

Also with plain lattice itself one can do this:

```
histogram(~ values | ind, stack(iris[1:4]), main = "Iris", xlab = "")
```